# A Fairly Simple Riddle

Tags: mathematics

A homeless man who lives on the streets has a smoking problem. However, since he can not buy cigarettes, he is forced to collect cigarette butts. He needs six butts to make a single cigarette. If he collects 216 butts, how many cigarettes can he make?

> Hint: After making six cigarettes and smoking them, he can use those butts to make another one.

Comment: Well, if the answer is really what people answered for the moment, your riddle hasn't any difficulty or any trap, so... :/

Answer (score 3):

> with 216 butts he can make 36 cigarettes.
>  with 36 butts he can make 6 cigarettes
>  with 6 butts he can make 1 cigarette 
>  so 36+6+1 = 43 cigarettes

Comment: Thanks for edit. I am new at this . I can't figure it out how to do that

Comment: He collected more than a carton of cigarette butts and only got < 3 packs out of them, smh. He should just ask me instead.

Comment: @B.Mert You have to put ">!" before your line, you only wrote ">" ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Initial 216 cigarette butts will give him 36 cigarettes. From the butts of those 36, he gets 6 more, and from the butts of those 6, he gets one more. So: 36 + 6 + 1 = 43

Answer (score 1):

> Seeing as he can make a cigarette from 6 butts, he smokes only 5/6 of each cigarette, that is 5 butts' worth. Thus, 216 butts is enough for floor(216/5) = 43 smokes of 5 butts each.