# The Chain Smokers

Tags: mathematics

The Chain Smokers in our neighborhood are revered for their magical ability. They can use five cigarette butts to make a full cigarette. One day, they collected a **1000** cigarette butts. How many cigarettes can they make, at **maximum**?

*Here's something pre-, **THE ANSWER IS NOT 200***

Comment: This looks like a math problem rather than a real puzzle

Comment: I think it's fair to call it a puzzle, but it's a *really old* puzzle...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Pretty sure, some similar puzzle would be present in the archives of this site.... This is a pretty famous one, even for kids..., there you go... http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33289/a-fairly-simple-riddle?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

They make

> 200 cigarettes from the 1000 butts, then
>  40 cigarettes from the resulting 200 butts, then
>  8 cigarettes from the resulting 40 butts, then
>  1 cigarette from the resulting 8 butts,
>  at which point they have four butts left and can't go further.

So the number is

> 249.

Comment: You've got the cigar.

Comment: The usual answer to this puzzle is that he then borrows a cigarette butt to make one more cigarette, and after he smokes it he can return the resulting butt he borrowed.

Comment: True. But there's no indication in the problem statement that anyone around is lending out cigarette butts, nor any [lateral-thinking] in the tags, so I maintain that my more straightforward answer is better.