# Winston the Hobo

Tags: mathematics

Winston the Hobo really loves smoking. Every $7$ cigarette butts he finds on the ground, he rolls the tobacco in a cigarette and smokes it.

Winston is very poor, so he actually rolls cigarettes with his own butts. For instance, if he finds $49$ butts, he'll smoke $7+1$ cigarettes: $7$ from the butts he found, and $1$ rolled from the butts of the cigarettes he smoked.

How many cigarettes does Winston smoke after he finds $n$ butts?

**Addendum**: the function $f(n)$ must not make use of the floor function.

Comment: Why don't you post your answer that does not involve the floor function? (I'm guessing that instead of $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{6} \rfloor$ you have something in mind like: "if $6m \le n - 1 < 6m + 6$, then the answer is $m$". Or "the answer is $((n-1) - ((n-1) \bmod 6)) / 6$". All of which are equivalent.)

Answer (score 7):

(Very similar questions have been asked and answered here before: [A Fairly Simple Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33289/a-fairly-simple-riddle) and [The Chain Smokers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41916/the-chain-smokers). This is different in that it asks for an answer for arbitrary $n$.)

Let's generalize a bit more and say that Winston can make a cigarette from $k$ butts.

Every time Winston makes a cigarette and smokes it, he reduces the number of butts by $k-1$. He can do this as long as there are at least $k$ butts; that is, as long as he ends up with at least one butt. So we can hide one of the butts and say that he just repeatedly turns $k-1$ butts to no butts (making a cigarette each time) until none remain. Therefore the number of cigarettes he makes is $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{k-1}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: I will add the requirement that the formula must not use the floor function. Does that make it more interesting?

Comment: If the answer equals a simple formula with a floor in it (which it does) then requiring that the formula not have an explicit floor in it just amounts to saying "find a way to write the floor function without using the floor symbol"...

Comment: @Lonidard: Will this lead to a more elegant solution or just to some song and dance to work around the floor function? If the latter, no, that's not more interesting.

Comment: This is not my point. I am saying that the case for this particolar $k$ does not require the use of floor function or equivalent forms.

Comment: The answer for this particular k is floor((n-1)/6). (Unless I've made a mistake, which of course I may have.) Are you saying that there is another way to write the function n -> floor((n-1)/6) that's appreciably better in some way?

Comment: $\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor=x-\{x\}$ :D

Comment: It seems unlikely that anyone is going to be unhappy with the floor function but happy with the fractional-part function. (Of course that's your point.) I am curious what sort of thing Lonidard has in mind.